# Pass getQueryLocator values to Batch Execute parameter

Tags: batch

I'm really struggling to learn this batchable process so i apologize ahead of time!!!
Having said that....

I am trying to kick off a limited batch record update process.  I think I have this part right now. 
I've built a scheduled class that calls my batch process:

```
//  In the scheduled class I'm going to update many records, 10 at a time.

OpportunityMajorGiftProspectBatch batch = new OpportunityMajorGiftProspectBatch(); 
Database.executeBatch(batch, 10);
```

**The Issue**

In my OpportunityMajorGiftProspectBatch class  I don't know how to pass the getQueryLocator records, (OpportunityContactRole.Contact.Id values) into the Execute statement's List 'Contact' context.  Do you know what I mean?  I'm looking up Contact Id's in the OpportunityContactRole so I can update Contact records in the execute section.

Thanks in advance for help on this.

Kevin

```
global class OpportunityMajorGiftProspectBatch implements Database.Batchable<sObject> {
// This class sets a Contact's Major_Gift_Prospect_Contact__c field to TRUE
// under the correct circumstances.

    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
        String query = 'Select contact.id, contact.Name from OpportunityContactRole WHERE Opportunity.DEPARTMENT_TYPE__C = \'Advancement\' AND Opportunity.DEPARTMENT_Sub_Type__C = \'Major Gifts\' AND Contact.Major_Gift_Prospect_Contact__c = false';
        return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
    }


    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<Contact> scope) {
         for(Contact c : scope)
         {
             c.Major_Gift_Prospect_Contact__c = true;
         }
         update scope;
    }   

    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you mix several things : the scope in the execute method is the records from the query define in the start. So in your case, OpportunityContactRole. You need to create a Map of contact while in the for loop :

```
global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<sObject> scope) {
     Map<Id,Contact> contactMap = new Map<Id,Contact>();
     for(sObject s : scope)
     {
        OpportunityContactRole ocr = (OpportunityContactRole)s;
        if(!contactMap.containsKey(ocr.Contact.Id))
        {
            Contact con = new Contact(Id=ocr.Contact.Id,Major_Gift_Prospect_Contact__c = true);
            contactMap.put(ocr.Contact.Id,con);
        }
     }
     update contactMap.values();
}
```